# JavaScript, как передавать аргумент в фукнцию?

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){ 
   casper.click(function(){
       console.log(i);// как здесь передать переменную 'i'??
   });   
}
```

Вопрос таков, как передавать аргумент в функцию, если функция создана на месте?

Comment: а что у вас делает эта функция? почему она в цикле и как это связано с кликом?

Comment: То что делает функция не важно, мне важно чтобы переменная 'i' передалась в функцию(тоесть чтобы click() видел эту переменную)

Comment: @humster_spb, он видать хочет получить индекс

Comment: @NurbekAbilev, в какой именно момент цикла клик должен видеть переменную? Вы понимаете, что такое цикл? Переменная i на каждой итерации увеличивается на 1. Если не задать какое-то условие выхода из цикла, то переменная i в конце цикла всегда будет равна length. И по клику всегда будет выводиться только это значение.

Comment: Создайте промежуточную переменную внутри цикла, её и выводите